# Unique polynomials in a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

**Let $f \in L^2 (0,1)$. Show that for any positive integer n there exists a unique polynomial $p_n$ of degree $\leq$ to $n$ such that $\|f-p\| \geq \|f- p_n\| $ for all polynomials $p$ of degree $\leq$ $n$.**

I've been playing around with properties of Hilbert spaces, triangle ineq., and schwarz ineq. but I cannot really get anything substantial going. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto the subspace of polynomials of degree at mosts $n$.

Comment: This is the distance minimizing property of Hilbert spaces. Note that the subspace in Jose27's comment is closed. So you can apply this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem

Comment: Jose27 could you elaborate further.